# Paytm checksum mismatch in ios swift4

Tags: arrays, swift4, paytm

I am Integrating paytm gateway in ios app when I generating checksum through api calling and pass this checksum with below param in web view

WEB VIEW is loading with Parms:

```
{

   "CALLBACK_URL" = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=SJ-1552029210215";

  "CHANNEL_ID" = WAP;
  CHECKSUMHASH = "FRMuR8LLFvg3wkIf6gp4BqVnNigr6WvUaSm9EVJIJo6Z5RicUvU7acRGZlEfK1FGoeNSqN53R0OphttHFnJuZ0lKeAZDvrG7Pr5ZnlzTEUw=";
  "CUST_ID" = 64;

   EMAIL = "jitu123@gmail.com";

  "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" = Retail;

    MID = rxazcv89315285244163;
   "MOBILE_NO" = 566789877;
   "ORDER_ID" = "SJ-1552029210215";
   "TXN_AMOUNT" = "246.0";
   WEBSITE = WEBSTAGING;
}
```

I am getting back below response

```
{
   "ORDERID" : "SJ-1552029210215",
   "MID" : "rxazcv89315285244163",
   "TXNAMOUNT" : "246.00",
   "BANKTXNID" : "",
   "RESPCODE" : "330",
   "STATUS" : "TXN_FAILURE",
   "CURRENCY" : "INR",
   "RESPMSG" : "Paytm checksum mismatch."
}
```

how can i solve paytm checksum mismatch issue???

Comment: please help @DionizB

Comment: please help @Hassan Imam

Comment: have u solved this bro.. I am also getting same error